# Displaying PDF on WebBrowser Control not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control

I Have a test.pdf and I want to display it inside in my form.

My code is very simple:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.wbPdf.Navigate(@"file:///<fullpath>\test.pdf#toolbar=0");
        }
```

and it's not working. It's showing me a white page with an "X".

But if I do instead this:

```
this.wbPdf.Navigate(@"file:///<fullpath>\test.pdf#toolbar=0", true);
```

the IE opened and it showed my pdf. Of course, I tried to use `false` in the second parameter and it's not working.

Also, if I tried to do something like

```
this.wbPdf.Navigate(@"http://www.google.com");
```

it showed me google, so I think there isn't any problem of configuration of `Web Browser Control`

Any ideas? I'm not will be able to have Acrobat Reader installed, so using ActiveX components is not an option (also, this project is in `x64` and I've read that this component is not working very well in `x64`).

I want to display the pdf only for viewing inside the form, not in another window.

Comment: so if I don't have any pdf installed on my machine, it wont shome anything? well that's a problem (in my machine just got Foxit, but when we implement is not expected to be anything)

Comment: I assume WinForm.  You need to tag this WinForm or WPF

Comment: please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439618/webbrowser-control-doesnt-display-the-pdf-file-into-the-winform-with-adobe-why/60014799#60014799

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the web browser control in WinForms relies on the default PDF reader (usually Acrobat Reader) for displaying PDF files. If you need to display PDF files without requiring any other piece of software to be installed, then you will probably need to use a PDF rendering library in your application. Some examples of PDF rendering libraries:

- [MuPDF](https://code.google.com/p/mupdf-converter/) A GPL/Commercial viewer with a .net wrapper, you need a commercial license for use on commercial closed-source applications.
- [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/) Commercial library for editing or displaying PDF files. *Disclaimer: I currently work as a developer of the library.*

Another option would be to create a local HTML5 page that renders the PDF file using the project [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/), then embeed that page on your web browser control. But [this will only work on Windows systems with IE 9.0 or above](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Required-Browser-Features).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and tried the same things you did. Here's what finally fixed it for me. I had Foxit PDF Reader installed, but this may apply to other PDF readers as well. I reinstalled Foxit, and during the installation I selected the "Open PDF files in web browser" option. (That may not be the exact name of the option - I'm going from memory.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).