# WebBrowser control doesn't display the Pdf file into the winform with Adobe. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control, adobe-reader

Here's my code to open the pdf file into the webBrowser control:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
         dlg.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf) |*.pdf;";
         dlg.ShowDialog();
         webBrowser1.Navigate(dlg.FileName);

    }
```

And here's my problem:

When I have Foxit Panthom like default pdf reader the pdf is displayed into the webBrowser, but when I set Adobe Reader (I try even with Sumatra Pdf) to default pdf reader the pdf file is displayed into a separated window. Why? Where I'm wrong?

I'm working with a Windows 7 Professional 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stopped working for us too after upgrading to Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
Following the instruction in [Adobe Help Center - Display PDF in browser](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html) is ok for us now.

Switch off and then on again.

Comment: it doesn't work on my project.. I've tried everything about that link.

Comment: Sorry to hear, which Adobe Acrobat version are you using?

Comment: For X (and maybe XI) we had similar problem and we resolved with Edit -> Preferences -> General -> uncheck "Enable Protected Mode At Startup".

Comment: nothing... I've tried both with checked and unchecked "Enable Protected Mode at Startup" and it's the same as before.

Comment: Nothing else to try, sorry cannot help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a painful bug that I solved in the following way when all the other proposed solutions failed to work for me.

1. Confirm that Adobe reader is properly configured to display content within the WebBrowser control. In Reader, Edit, Preferences, Security (Enhanced) and uncheck Enable Protected Mode at Startup.
2. Confirm that Internet Explorer has enabled Reader. In IE, click the toolgear icon, choose Manage Add Ons, Click the drop down box on Show currently loaded Add ons to select All Add-ons. You should see Adobe Reader listed as Enabled.

**3) You are now ready to solve this frustrating problem. REMOVE ADOBE ACROBAT READER DC FROM YOUR COMPUTER and then IMMEDIATELY RE-INSTALL IT.**

4. In ACROBAT READER DC, once again, Edit, Preferences, Security (Enhanced) and uncheck Enable Protected Mode at startup.